# Returning empty promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I'm implementing this [button](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypqkcf-eduhze?file=app%2Fprogress-spinner%2Fprogress-spinner.component.ts) in my app.

In my button component I have:

```
  @Input() callback: () => Promise<null>;
  onClick() {
    this.spinnerService.show();
    this.callback().then(() => {
      this.spinnerService.hide();
    }, () => {
      this.spinnerService.hide();
    });
  }
```

(I don't use async / await because the "tech lead" doesn't want me too)

The component template:

```
<my-button [callback]="doSomething">
</my-button>
```

Everything works fine when I pass this kind of code to the component's input:

```
doSomething = () => {
  return myService.doSomething()
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) => console.log('promise resolved'));
}
```

But I need to break from this function earlier:

```
doSomething() {
  if (condition) {
    return;
  }
  return myService.doSomething()
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) => console.log('promise resolved'));
}
```

I get

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I've tried forcing a promise with the same result

```
  if (condition) {
    return Promise.resolve(null);
    // or
    return new Promise((resolve) => { resolve(null); });
  }
```

Comment: Which 'then' property is causing issue?

Comment: @Sharcoux, the then from the button component. First code block

Comment: `(I don't use async / await because the "tech lead" doesn't want me too)

` StackOverflow can't help you with inter-company egos ;)

Comment: Promise is not the issue here. You are focusing on the if(condition) located before the incriminated code.

Comment: How strange. I tried something similar and it worked perfectly. Have you tried to check what that doSomething() method truly returns when the condition is met? I mean, you haven't got any library that breaks Promise.resolve, don't you? Can you do this and see what it returns? `console.log(this.callback())` in your `onClick()` method

Comment: @Sharcoux .toPromise() is the code that works. The error arises when I meet the condition.

Comment: No, that's not it. As he said, the code worked before the condition is added. And `toPromise` returns a `Promise` as it is an `Observable` operator.

Comment: the faulty `then` is the one in `onClick`, which depends on `doSomething` returning a Promise. He's saying that `Promise.resolve(null)` does not, in fact, return a Promise, but `undefined`. Could you do that logging I asked you to?

Comment: My bad, i dind't go up eneough and miscounted the code blocks ^^'

Comment: logging callback returns undefined in any case (working or not)

Comment: Uh, we definitely need to see more code. How are you assigning `callback` its value? Can we see that? Don't be shy posting code, because something strange is happening here

Comment: @OscarPaz I posted the template of the button and how dosomething is defined (because it looks weird) I need to do doSomething = () => {} because it looses the context of promise when passed as input. I'll try to post a reproducible code when I can

Comment: Yes, to pass the function to a child component you need to define it with the arrow syntax or you lose the context of the defining class. Have you tried to set a breakpoint on the call to this.callback(), enter it and see what it does? It would be the easiest way to solve this issue

Comment: FYI: A promise should never be NULL (or empty). A promise can only be fulfilled or rejected. So you would always send a Promise with whatever value. On the logic side it then gets reject or was fulfilled. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for further reference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this input

```
@Input() callback: () => Promise<null>;
```

there is no guarantee that it's assigned to proper value. Additional check if `callback` was specified should be added.

A safer way to manage this is to use `async` functions in these places because they consistently use promises:

```
  async onClick() {
    this.spinnerService.show();

    try {
      if (this.callback)
        await this.callback()
    } finally {
      this.spinnerService.hide();
    }
  }
```

`doSomething` is supposed to return a promise unconditionally, and this can also be addressed with `async`:

```
async doSomething() {
  if (!condition)
    return myService.doSomething().toPromise();
}
```

If `async` functions can't be used for some reason (although there are no good ones, because they are spec-compliant, first-class citizens in TypeScript), promises should be consistently processed in functions (also helpful for testing). `doSomething` isn't properly typed, and this allows improper function return. It should be:

```
  onClick(): Promise<void> {
    this.spinnerService.show();

    return Promise.resolve(this.callback ? this.callback() : undefined)
    .catch(() => {})
    .then(() => {
      this.spinnerService.hide();
    });
  }
```

and

```
doSomething(): Promise<void> {
  if (condition) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  return myService.doSomething().toPromise();
}
```

And the type of `callback` will be `Promise<void>`, not `Promise<null>`.

Regular (non-arrow) `doSomething` method should be bound to `this` in constructor.

Comment: Awesome explanation an really nice to see how async/await compares to classic promises. You saved me a huge headache.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
doSomething() {
  if (condition) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> reject('Some Error Message'));
  }
  return myService.doSomething()
    .toPromise()
    .then((response) => console.log('promise resolved'));
}
```

Comment: where are you calling this function?

Comment: It's passed as an input to the button component (first code block), I justed edited how it's initialized

Comment: @gyc This is the only place in your code where `.then` is accessed on undefined. If this answer doesn't work for you, code changes weren't applied for some reason, or there's some other problem you didn't show.